# Is CKMarkNotificationsReadOperation device specific or app specific?

Tags: push-notification, cloudkit, cknotification

Does anyone know if marking a CKNotification as read affects all devices or just the device that read the notification?

If it affects all devices, then what's the purpose of marking it read if you can just send the previous server change token to get all the unprocessed ones?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It affects all devices.

The purpose of marking it read is so that the other devices also know and is achieved by checking the notificationType on each notification returned from CKFetchNotificationChangesOperation.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere?